# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to+\infty}(x+1)^{1+\frac{1}{x+1}}-x^{1+\frac{1}{x}}$

Tags: limits

How to prove that:

$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left((x+1)^{1+\frac{1}{x+1}}-x^{1+\frac{1}{x}}\right)=1
$$

By MVT if $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}f'(x)=L$ then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(f(x+1)-f(x)\right)=L$ but I want to see if there are other ways, involving less sophisticated tools.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a less sophisticated tool than the MVT that applies to transcendental functions, just for comparison?

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$(x+1)^{1+\frac{1}{x+1}} = (x+1)\cdot(x+1)^{\frac{1}{x+1}}=(x+1)\cdot\left(1+\frac{\log x}x+O\left(\frac{\log^2 x}{x^2}\right)\right)$$

$$x^{1+\frac{1}{x}}=x\cdot x^{\frac{1}{x}}=x\cdot\left(1+\frac{\log x}x+O\left(\frac{\log^2 x}{x^2}\right)\right)$$

therefore

$$(x+1)^{1+\frac{1}{x+1}}-x^{1+\frac{1}{x}} =1+\frac{\log x}x+O\left(\frac{\log^2 x}{x^2}\right)\to 1$$

---

For the expansion we have used that

$$x^{\frac{1}{x}}=e^{\frac{\log x}x}=1+\frac{\log x}x+O\left(\frac{\log^2 x}{x^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$A=(x+1)^{1+\frac{1}{x+1}}\qquad\text{and} \qquad B=x^{1+\frac{1}{x}}$$ Taking logarithms
$$\log(A)=\log (x)+\frac{\log (x)+1}{x}-\frac{2 \log (x)-1}{2
   x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$
$$A=e^{\log(A)}=x+(\log (x)+1)+\frac{\log ^2(x)+2}{2
   x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$
$$\log(B)=\log (x)+\frac{\log (x)}{x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$
$$B=e^{\log(B)}=x+\log (x)+\frac{\log ^2(x)}{2   x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$
$$A-B=1+\frac 1x+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

If you take more terms
$$A-B=1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{(\log (x)-1)^2}{2x^2}+\cdots$$ which is a very good approximation as soon as $x \geq 2$. It shows a maximumn absolute relative error of $0.28$% for $x=4.07$.